# Print out the sum of 1/n

Tags: c

**This is the C problem and i need your help.**

I have checked my code lots of time but I can not print out the result.
Question: input n and print out S = 1-1/2+1/3-1/4... +-1/n with abs(1/n)>e

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
float checkQ3(int n){
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<= n; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            sum += -1/i;
        }else{
            sum += 1/i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
int main(){
    int n; printf("Input n: "); scanf("%d",&n);
    float sum1 = checkQ3(n);
    printf("%f",sum1);
}
```

Then there is no ouput, I have tried so many way but it did not work,please help me.

Comment: Hint #1: Integer division problem. Hint #2: Div by Zero.

Comment: `i` is an `int`, so `1/i` is an `int`, i.e. `0`.

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages. Please don't tag multiple languages, only the language you're actually working in.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I am new to code, It's great to help me know what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop starts at 0, rather than one resulting in division-by-zero. Edit your code to the following:

```
for(int i = 1; i<= n; i++){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        sum += -1/i;
    }else{
        sum += 1/i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to distinguish

- my program ran but gave the wrong result
- my program crashed because I asked to do something impossible

Yours is the second one

I got

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF695651997 in ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero.

You must surely have got a similar error message too

Anyway run this code in your head with i == 0

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        sum += -1 / i; <<<<<========
```

Comment: I did not have that message :( It can be run in terminal but there is no output, but I have solved that problem, many thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

Start your loop form `1` So that you don't face any exception

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     s+= i%2==0 ? -1/i : 1/i;

 return s;
```